# Silverlight for Mac and Is Silverlight dead?

Tags: silverlight, html

so i have been writing a prototype application in Silverlight for the last 3 months, although I am enjoying the technology and it has been very useful for the current task, I have read and been told from varies sources that the technology could no longer be supported and HTML5 is the way forward? Was just wondering if there was some solid information on this from Microsoft and if so where it could be found? Done some googling and just found blogs with sparse info.

Also if anyone one had any thoughts on the state of the mac version of silverlight? I have run some tests so far and the applications performance is really poor compared to silverlight running on windows.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It will eventually die, even if Microsoft doesn't say. Currently they are pushing it for WP7 dev, but when the new sdk is released, it will also allow html/js apps for the phone, which basically kills silverlight completely.

Comment: I don't think anyone can reasonably answer this question unless they are on the Silverlight team at Microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

I'd have to look for the articles and links again but, long ago, Microsoft would not answer any questions about Silverlight and, more recently, has announced they do not encourage and will no longer develop Silverlight for the desktop. They now encourage HTML5 usage as evidenced by Windows8 which won't even be able to directly run Silverlight at all.

Interview with Microsoft's Bob Mulia by Mary-Jo Foley:
[Our strategy has shifted](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-our-strategy-with-silverlight-has-shifted/7834)

> So what’s a developer to make of Microsoft’s messaging (or lack
>   thereof) about Silverlight at its premiere developer conference?
>
> I asked Bob Muglia, the Microsoft President in charge of the company’s
>   server and tools business, that very question and got what I consider
>   to be the clearest answer yet about how Microsoft is evolving its
>   Silverlight strategy.
>
> “Silverlight is our development platform for Windows Phone,” he said.
>   Silverlight also has some “sweet spots” in media and line-of-business
>   applications, he said.
>
> But when it comes to touting Silverlight as Microsoft’s vehicle for
>   delivering a cross-platform runtime, “our strategy has shifted,”
>   Muglia told me.

And, about the Mac:

> “But HTML is the only true cross platform solution for everything,
>   including (Apple’s) iOS platform,” Muglia said.

More links with Microsoft interviews:

[Microsoft has abandoned Silverlight in Metro](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/09/Metro-Plug-ins)

[Microsoft's Silverlight has been dropped for HTML5](http://www.hightechnewstoday.com/apr-2011-high-tech-news-archives/74-apr-13-2011-high-tech-news.shtml)

Comment: But still, I remember reading that the xaml notation will be even more relevant  within WP and Metro apps. Have u seen [this page](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-8-and-the-future-of-XAML-Part-1-An-overview-of-the-Windows-8-platform.aspx)?

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks a lot. Been reading the articles, they are very useful.

Comment: @Rob just the whole thing makes me want to cry. Hacky and buggy javascript *should* never replace a type-safe, object oriented, JIT compiled language (C#) with support for functional elements (Linq / Lambdas) extensive framework and of course, tried and tested in distributed enterprise systems ...

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson - This sort of thing happened to me as .NET transitioned from 1.x to 2.x and we lost a year's development time, untold thousands of dollars and I think a few lives in the process.

Comment: @Rob at least .NET 1.x -2.x was still a strongly typed language! A quote from that InfoQ article says it all: "But even more pressing is JavaScript itself, whose syntax and dynamic nature make it very difficult to write large, modular applications."

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson - Maybe Google's Dart has a place after all.

Comment: -1 @Rob you are really speculating, but acting like all this is fact. The strategy shift was to ADD HTML, but remove Silverlight.. there's been more said.. if you read what the folks who know have said, you get a slightly different picture.. one that could go either way..

Comment: @DevTheo - Quoting Microsoft execs is not speculation on my part.

Comment: @DevTheo - btw, the other two links are newer and from different MS execs.

Comment: The great "Microsoft's Silverlight has been dropped in favor of HTML5" fud is still alive and kicking.  This started when it was revealed that you could create metro apps using HTML5 and js via WinRT.  The rest of this is speculation about the state of software 2+ years out.  Considering MS only recently stopped supporting VB6 (i.e., stopped worrying about breaking it with windows updates) and WP7 is essentially SL, I think it will be around for awhile.  Will it evolve?  Of course.  Be abandoned?  Doubt it unless something serious happens.

Comment: @Will, one could argue that it's alive and well in the new form of XAML + C#/VB in WinRT.. Anyway, this is such a stupid discussion, it's all hearsay and speculation..

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather not take part in these discussions, but the one comment said it best. None of us can reasonably answer this question.. even IF "MS' strategy has changed." It could change back. The exec who said this -- Bob Muglia-- announced a month later (maybe it was 1.5 months) announced he was leaving the company (and is no longer with Microsoft today).

The only real indicators we have are that they haven't announced an end of life date, and there is another technology that uses Silveright that came out called VS LightSwitch (not just the phone). Not saying that any of this means that Sivlerlight is sticking around, BUT we really don't know. The problem is more complex than a fanboy of any type can really answer.

I'd like to think it will be around for a while (and I personally am basing a new project on it). Not to name drop, but there is a former Silverlight and Win8 evangelist who recently left MS to go work for Disney (where I know they do a lot of Silverlight work, yet).

Comment: Microsoft dropped Silverlight from Bing Maps, as did SkyDrive but I know nothing about SkyDrive. It's what Microsoft does with their own product that's more significant than what Disney is doing.

Comment: I started answering this and ultimately ending up agreeing that it's not a good question.. That said, Bing Maps and SkyDrive are 2 technologies MS is trying to bring to the masses.. it would be stupid to pick a technology that is only available on Desktops... I wouldn't have chosen Silverlight for something like that before the whole Muglia quotes.. You have to look at what you are attempting to do. Bottom line Windows XP -- no longer supported; VB6 -- no longer supported (I think); Silverlight -- supported (for now at least).

Comment: @Rob: [Not sure if clueless or troll.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj1ws.png)

Comment: @Will - Not my source but I Googled this for you: http://goo.gl/n0q0s

Comment: @Rob: Dude, did you read that article?  Protip:  Scroll to the **Update:** section.  *"To recap, the Active-X/3D change has nothing to do with Silverlight, our post was off the mark there and for that we apologize."*  Apologies to DevTheo for filling up his inbox.